# Save online image locally

Tags: react-native

I am getting a profilepicture from my server via a URL:

```
<Image
    source={
      profilePictureUrl !== ''
        ? {uri: API_URL + '/' + profilePictureUrl}
        : PROFILE_DEFAULT
    }
    style={{width: 200, height: 200, borderRadius: 100}}
  />
```

How can I save this image on my device so it is available when the user is offline?

Comment: You'll want to use a file system library like RNFS or expo file system, and then create an image wrapper component. You'll want the wrapper component to take a url and style as props. Use async storage to keep track of downloaded images url and local path location. If the item exists in async storage, then use the path provided from async storage to render the image. If not, download it using the filesystem, write the url and path location to async storage

Comment: If you are using expo then [expo-asset](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/v48.0.0/sdk/asset/#downloadasync) already kind of do this, but it looks like the file is downloaded in the cache, which may not have the same amount of permanence as the method above. Also with the method above it is possible make the images available outside of your application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [prefetch](https://reactnative.dev/docs/image#prefetch) method of Image component which download image and store in disk cache for later use.

Call this `await Image.prefetch(API_URL + '/' + profilePictureUrl);` once when user is online before showing this image if you have profile picture url.

Comment: Does the image get's stored when I close and reopen the app?

Comment: Yes image component load image from cache automatically all you need to prefetch when you have internet connection.

Comment: @JaRoMaster Just to add more you can do this also in FastImage and if there is so much images to download and show for offline you have to go with RNFS to download images in directory of iOS or Android and use local file system path when offline.

Comment: I'll only need to cache one image (max 100kb), so I think going with prefetch is the way to go

Answer (score 1):

that depends on the purpose of the usage of this image
do you want to cache it then you can go with `FastImage`

```js
import FastImage from 'react-native-fast-image'

const YourImage = () => (
    <FastImage
        style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }}
        source={{
            uri: 'https://unsplash.it/400/400?image=1',
            priority: FastImage.priority.normal,
        }}
        resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.contain}
    />
)
```

but if you want to use it for offline purposes then you can go with the option of using `@react-native-async-storage/async-storage` or any other storages that your

```js
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

// Save the image to async storage
await AsyncStorage.setItem('profilePicture', uri);
```

Comment: Wouldn't this just save the uri and try to download it again after the launch of the app? I want the image to be available offline

Comment: Or does Asyncstorage save the image itself when a uri is passed?

Comment: no, the image will not be download with `FastImage` again if the URL didn't change, so it will be always saved even if there is no internet
the same you can use async-storage or even redux-presist or even realm if you want more database
but I don't think it's too complicated so you can just use `FastImage`
use this property with cache `cache: FastImage.cacheControl.immutable`